# Url is working but it's giving page not found error when i check that in websiteoptimization

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, url

while validating my application urls in [websiteoptimization](http://analyze.websiteoptimization.com) or [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/), some urls are giving 404 page not found error. But while trying that url in browsers it's working fine.

Url which is causing this problem [url](http://54.165.121.59:9999/livetv/bbc-world-news-world-business-report-2015-02-04-08-45-00) . Please let me know what could be the actual problem with this url.

Comment: you'll need to post a little more information I'm afraid.  A common linking mistake is to reference a URL as HTTP or HTTPS, in cases where it only accepts one or the other.

Comment: I notice your URL is http://54.165.121.59:9999, which is a pretty nonstandard URL, so it's possible this is not a format the URL parser on these sites supports.  To be safe I would convert this into a standard domain name.

Also when I input your URL into a browser like TOR, I get this error: 

```Not Found

Rails.root: /mnt/circles_portal/dittov2/web_portal```
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

```app/helpers/application_helper.rb:238:in `route_not_found'
app/controllers/media_controller.rb:1273:in `rescue in details'
app/controllers/media_controller.rb:1187:in `details' ```

Comment: @Kelseydh how did u get this error? Please help to reproduce that error.

Comment: Sorry... I am no longer getting that error for your site on TOR, possibly because your site or server has changed since I did that.  Please ignore it.

[To explain again what I did:  I used the URL you provided with the TOR browser (look it up if you don't know what it is), which can be a crude way to test how a website loads from an ISP or IP that isn't your own.]

Anyways, as for your original problem:  Again I would again try to use a URL with a standard domain or DNS.  It's possible the non-standard URL you're using conflicts with how those websites parse URL's.  (Contacting them may help)

Comment: @Kelseydh I fixed the issue. The actual issue was i have begin rescue blocks. While running the code in application it's executing the code which is in rescue block. But while pasting the url in facebook it's validation the code which is in begin block.